# ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] 既存の接続はリモート ホストに強制的に切断されました。を解決したいです

Tags: python, api

プログラミング初心者です。binanceというサイトとapiで通信したいのですが、コードをループさせてから数分後(5~30分後)にタイトルのエラーが出て強制的に通信が切断されてしまいます。
作ったコードは以下の通りです。

```
import configparser
import json
from binance.client import Client 
import time
from datetime import datetime
from binance.enums import *
from binance.exceptions import *

inifile = configparser.ConfigParser()
inifile.read('../config/config.ini', 'UTF-8')
 
api_key = inifile.get('settings', 'API_KEY')
api_secret = inifile.get('settings', 'API_SECRET')

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    prices=client.get_all_tickers()
    print(prices)
```

プログラムを開始させて数分後に必ず以下のエラーが出て強制的に切断されます。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 426, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 268, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] 既存の接続はリモート ホストに強制的に切断されました。

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 726, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 410, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 734, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 426, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 268, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, '既存の接続はリモート ホストに強制的に切断されました。', None, 10054, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kihon.py", line 24, in <module>
    prices=client.get_all_tickers()
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 438, in get_all_tickers
    return self._get('ticker/allPrices')
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 237, in _get
    return self._request_api('get', path, signed, version, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 202, in _request_api
    return self._request(method, uri, signed, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 196, in _request
    self.response = getattr(self.session, method)(uri, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 543, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, '既存の接続はリモート ホストに 強制的に切断されました。', None, 10054, None))
```

APIリクエスト上限回数は1200回/分で、これが原因ではないみたいです。
ちなみにこのエラーはWifiが切れてしまったときにも出ます。
しかし、回線が強いwifiで有線でやっても無線でやっても、スマホのテザリングでやってもエラーが出てしまいます。
一か月以上このエラーが出続けているので投稿させてもらいました。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: こちらのapi以外の方法で対象サイトへのpythonからのアクセスは出来ているのでしょうか？

Comment: 参考: [Binance errors · Issue #3897 · ccxt/ccxt](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/issues/3897) "You're have either sent too many requests already – in that case **Binance may ban you for periods from 10 minutes to an hour on average**"

Comment: ＠metropolis I don't believe my IP address have still banned or restricted 'cause after one whole week since my last request, I've tried this code again but this error occued again

Comment: merinoさんコメントありがとうございます。api以外というのはブラウザで接続できるかという意味でしょうか。それでしたら接続することができます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

調べたところ内部で呼んでいる [`ticker/allPrices` は deprecated となり `ticker/prices` に変更された](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2019-11-13)ようで、[そのドキュメント](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#symbol-price-ticker)をみるとこう書いてあります

> Weight: 1 for a single symbol; 2 when the symbol parameter is omitted

この API を呼び出すウェイトはパラメータを省略すると **1 ではなく 2** なんですね。というわけで呼べる回数は 1200 回ではなく 600 回まででした。

#### 追記

どうやらこれっぽいです。
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56554869/13319818
`binance` 内で使われている `urllib3` というライブラリがセッションを使い回すと https コネクションを張りっぱなしにするらしく、タイムアウトになっても再接続してくれないのが原因のようです。ですので対策としてはリンク先にあるように例外をキャッチしたら送信し直し、とするしかないようです。

Comment: Akihitoさん、回答ありがとうございます。一分間に呼び出している回数は60回なので上限回数は関係していないと思われます。ちなみに他のリクエストでも同様のエラーが出てしまいます。他の要因などは考えられますでしょうか。

Comment: Oh, 普通にソース読み間違えてました。もうちょっと考えます。

Comment: 例外をキャッチするという方法で無事解決いたしました。本当にありがとうございました！